# How to distinguish maven and gradle from Travis logs using regexp

Tags: regex, maven, logging, gradle

Context: I'm currently working on a research tool which needs to mine on Travis API to get information on builds from thousands of projects on Github. I want to find the best way to recognize if the projects are using Maven or Gradle as building tool.

I retrieve logs from Travis Builds and parse them, for now I'm using the following pattern for maven:

```
^(-------------------------------------------------------|\[INFO\] Reactor Summary:)$
```

and this one for gradle:

```
^(:[\w-]+)?:test[\w-]*$
```

Problem is I found everyday new projects that do not fit those regexp: then do you have any idea to improve them to spot a maximum of projects without false positive?

Edit: I'm mostly interested in projects which launch tests, that's why I started with those regexp.

Comment: is `INFO` `test` and `Reactor Summary` fixed?

Comment: First, I must precise that I mostly interested on project that launches tests. And frankly I mostly advanced to those regexp by experience: most maven logs I encounter have the [INFO] Reactor Summary line, except if you launch maven in quiet mode: then I can catch some line of dashes when tests are launched. And for gradle, most of the project have some test tasks, prefixed with "test".

Comment: Why parsing the logs ...why not partsing the projects ?

Comment: Can you look at `travis.yml` in the root of the github project?

Comment: @khmarbaise parsing the project means to use the GitHub API and consume tokens and time: I have a large number of projects then parsing logs is more interesting to me.

@LanceJava the `travis.yml` file contain generally a call to a bash script which will contain instruction for calling maven or gradle.

Comment: I'd say a large number of projects will call `mvn` or `gradlew` directly and you should definately try this first. Note: I think you can get this directly from travis rather than using github api's (see [here](https://travis-ci.org/uklance/tader/jobs/157329406/config))

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you... a project which switched from maven to gradle

- [tader building with maven](https://travis-ci.org/uklance/tader/builds/65802404)
- [tader building with gradle](https://travis-ci.org/uklance/tader/builds/157329405)

Perhaps you could have a regex that says

- If "mvn" appears in the logs before "gradle" or "gradlew" then it's a maven project
- If "gradle" or "gradlew" appears before "mvn" then it's a gradle project

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but the problem is that some project I inspect could have "gradle" or "mvn" in their name: so it's much more difficult to use regexp on those commands...

Comment: I think it'll be a guess whatever you do. If there's a `build.gradle` file and no `pom.xml` I think it's safe to assume it's a gradle build (and vice versa).

Comment: ok but to detect that I have to use GH API, or to clone the project and I don't want to do that for thousands of projects...
I agree it's a guess, I just want to optimize it :)